# Assume $K/E$ is a finite galois extension. Let $\alpha$ be algebraic do automorphism map it to any other roots?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Assume $K/E$ is a finite Galois extension. Let $\alpha$ be algebraic over $E$,let $\beta$ be a root of $\alpha$'s minimal polynomial over $E$, is there an automorphisms of $K$ that maps $\alpha\to \beta$?

In all the cases I have done, when i look at the generators of the basis, it always turns out that we have enough mapping to exhaust all roots. This got me thinking if that is always the case. It is clear that any automorphism of $K$ maps $\alpha$ to another root of $m_{\alpha}$ but it is not clear that for any root, there is an automorphism that maps $\alpha$ to it. I suspect it to be false but I have no proof of that. I tried a simple case first.

$[E(\alpha,\beta):E(\alpha)][E(\alpha):E]=m*n$ the generators of the basis are $\alpha,\beta$, there are $mn$ automorphisms and so if $\alpha$ gets mapped to any root (there are $n$ of them) then $\beta$ must have degree $m$ which might not always be the case (I think)

Could someone tell me what is the truth?

Comment: This is true, Galois acts transitively on roots of an irreducible polynomial (all over the ground field $E$).

Comment: @TokenToucan IS there an easy proof of that fact? I am using Dummit and Foot and I dont see that as a theorem. Perhaps I missed it though. Also, would this mean that generators always have "flipped" orders? Like if $K/E$ is of degree $a$ and it has two generators then if one of them has degree $b$ then the other one has degree $a/b$?

Comment: It is certainly in Dummit and Foote, I can look later. It doesn't imply that fact you wrote about generators, eg take $K = E(\alpha,\alpha+1)$. Both have the same degree. You are forgetting to consider that the degree of $\alpha$ over $E(\beta)$ might be smaller than its degree over $E$, I think.

Comment: Use that E[x] mod the minimal polynomial is isomorphic to E[any root of the minimal polynomial] and the isomorphism extension property/theorem to extend to the Galois extension in question.

Comment: @TokenToucan I see, so there is an isomorphism between $E(\alpha)$ and $E(\beta)$ and that isomorphism can be extended to an automorphism of $K$ and so there is an automorphism that maps $\alpha$ to $\beta$. The existence of such automorphism is guaranteed by isomorphism extension theorem (which I dont think is in dummet as well but i might have missed that, my professor was skipping some stuff)

Comment: Actually i recant that statement. on page 519 I think we have the relevant theorem, (we just need to use primitive element theorem to apply it)

Comment: It seems I misplaced my copy, so I can't find a reference there but it really has to be since they're important for proving the fundamental theorem of galois theory - but maybe the weren't separated as standalone theorems/propositions. In Lang see V.2.7 and V.2.8.